# How to draw a path line on a map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion.
I am trying to draw a line (path) on a map using coordinates.
I can run it in my app but I see no lines on the map (and no errors either).

```
@mapview = MKMapView.alloc.initWithFrame(view.bounds)
@mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard
@mapview.delegate = self
@mapview.showsUserLocation = true
@mapview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight

view.addSubview(@mapview)
```

**Then I try to draw the line**

```
path = [CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(41.878114,-87.629798), CLLocationCoordinate2D.new(41.865947,-87.622576)]

pointers = Pointer.new(CLLocationCoordinate2D.type, path.length)
pointers[0] = path[0]
pointers[1] = path[1]

polyLine = MKPolyline.polylineWithCoordinates(pointers, count:2)

@mapview.addOverlay(polyLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert of ruby, but in order to actually see an overlay view on a map you need to set your class as the map's delegate and implement the `– mapView:viewForOverlay:` protocol method, where you need to return the actual `MKPolyLineView` object for the map to show!

In Objective C I would simply implement this method as:

```
 - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
 {
    if ( [overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyLine class]] {
       MKPolyLineView *polyView = [[MKPolyLineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
       return polyView;
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How problem is how to turn this into ruby code (the varibles): (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay

Comment: @JonathanClark: Read all about it here: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/#_object_model